# How to use ROS with GTK+?

Tags: ros, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

My goal is to write an interface for a robot.
There are several requirements:

1. The interface should be written in C using GTK+ library.
2. The result should be compatible with ROS.
   The question is how to do this in the most correct and simple way?
   (I am a completely new "GUI writer" and a new user of ROS).

I have started from this tutorial page "http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/image-viewer.c.html", and trued to install "Anjuta" (which seems to be a user-friendly, GUI dedicated environment), but I have revealed that it is not compatible with ROS...

Thanks in advance,
Felix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11440/how-to-use-ros-with-gtk+?/) by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does it have to be C only (i.e. not C++)? Then you will have problems with ROS as that is written in C++. If you just want to write C-code, but compile as C++ that's fine.

Other than that I would start from the ROS side, i.e. work through the ROS tutorials and create a basic ROS-package. Once you are familiar with that adding GTK code is just like adding any other library to ROS. You might be able to find examples for integrating GUI code into ROS as GTK + ROS packages. Currently I only know of ROS + Qt/wxWidgets, but the principle should be the same.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use either Qt, GTK+ in C, or GTKmm (a C++ port for GTK+). There are examples of using Qt in the eros stack [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_qt_tutorials). There's also a good example of using GTK+ with ROS [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ccny_ground_station). Personally, I have used [GTKmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/) for my GUI development in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1